# xml child element node or attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xdoc

I have a xml schema with nested xml elements and following is the small piece of that

```
<aa>
    <id extension="xx" root="56" />
    <name>demo</name>
    <telecom use="emer" value="tel:34444" />
</aa>

<bb>
   <value value="12345" />
</bb>
<cc>
   <value value="234567" />
</cc>
```

From this, I have to get the value of "name tag" under "aa tag", last attribute (tel:) of telecom tag, and attribute value of the "value tag" (which is found under  bb tag and cc tag)

I tried the following code, but it's not getting exactly what I am expecting.

```
xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("aa")
                              || x.Name.LocalName.Equals("telecom") && 
                              (x.FirstAttribute.Equals("EC")
                               || x.Name.LocalName.Equals("bb")
                               || x.Name.LocalName.Equals("cc"))
```

Please provide the solution for this issue.

Comment: Is this your schema? Can it be changed? Having the tel attribute as part of the value attribute difficult. 
Can you edit with exactly what you hope to get as the result?

Comment: thanks for replying, it's not my schema, i will fetch this schema while on accessing a service

Comment: Can you explain and post an example of exactly what you're trying to select? What do you want to get from your code?

Comment: I am having a ListCollection to fetch the values from this xml

I want to load ("12345" from bb-value tag, "234567" from cc-value tag, name-tag value "demo" , telecom last attribute value (tel:34444)

Comment: @SiddarthVarunesh, could you please post exact xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the appropriate descendant of each of your value and then by using proper linq query you can select desired values

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

        var name = doc.Descendants("organisation").Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "name").Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault();
        var tel = doc.Descendants("organisation").Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "telecom").Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        var bb_value = doc.Descendants("startdate").Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "value").Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        var cc_value = doc.Descendants("enddate").Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "value").Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine($"name: {name} \ntel: {tel} \nbb_value: {bb_value} \ncc_value: {cc_value}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Whenever my answer was helpful to you then you can mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: Hi Tried this , but i am returning null value, following is my actual schema will look like (edited due to confidential)<rootabc xmlns="aaaaa">
  <ControlAct><record><communicationFunctionSnd><organisation> <id extension="cfff" root="2.8999" /> <name>demo</name><telecom use="EC" value="tel:123445" /></organisation></communicationFunctionSnd> <demo2<info15><npfitlc:contentId/><Information><component><startdate><value value="201505100000" /></startdate></component <component1> <enddate><value value="201805100000" /> </enddate>  </component1></<Information></info15> </control>

Comment: your latest provide xml is not in correct format means closing nodes are missing but anyways I updated my answer so just try to replace `aa` with `organisation`, `bb` with `startdate` and `cc` with `enddate` in my answer. see the answer carefully i updated it. and let me know upon same :)

Comment: I didn't receive any response from you. does my answer solved your problem? if yes then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green otherwise I will delete this answer :)